# android - LinearLayout (Horizontal) - auto space between items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android LinearLayout and at the button I have buttons that I want to display in one line - I've put the in a horizontal layout so it will be next to each other - so far so good.

Here is my problem - the buttons are right next to each other, and what I would like is to have them take the screen  with spaces between them and padding from the right and left to the first and last buttons are not stuck to the border of the screen.

here's my layout xml (just the `LinearLayout` (Horizontal) part):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnHelpLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_help" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHelp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn_help"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnShareLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_share" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvShare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn_share"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnAboutLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_about" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAbout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn_about"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnSettingsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_settings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn_settings"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

how can I have it centered and with spaces?

thanks

Comment: Can u post a screen  how it should look?

Comment: Can you please post ans screen shot what looks you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the child container's (the `LinearLayout's` *btnHelpLayout*, *btnShareLayout*, *btnAboutLayout* and *btnSettingsLayout*) `android:layout_width` attributes to `"0dip"` and set a new attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` in all child containers (**Not** the `Buttons` and `TextViews`).

This will make them occupy the same space and give you a uniform look.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnHelpLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_help" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHelp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_help"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnShareLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_share" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_share"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnAboutLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_about" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAbout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_about"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnSettingsLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_settings"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Vlad: I am aware of that. And I am not sure where you picked that up. My post does not say that anywhere. Do read up on it again. Unless it was an "FYI" statement.

Comment: @Vlad: Absolutely. It is a valid property. See the official doc linked for more on that: [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)